# Trying to fix "subscript out of range error" on simple copy paste

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm kind of trying to teach myself VB in order to automate some stuff at my job.  I've almost got what I need but I'm having so much trouble with a line that was literally copied and pasted from a different macro (and it worked just fine in the other one).  This time, however, I keep running into the runtime error 9: subscript out of range.  I'm simply trying to copy one column from one workbook to another.  What could possibly be going wrong?

```
    Workbooks("BAYS-0058.xlsx").Sheets("Raw Data").Range("A:A").Copy Destination:=
        Workbooks("WO163553.xlsx").Sheets("Raw Data").Range("D:D")
```

It seems like it should be so simple and its driving me insane.  Also thanks to anyone who takes the time to help out.

Comment: The subscript out of range is probably on the `.Sheets("Raw Data")`. VBA is actually indexing into an Array of sheets with that helper method.

Comment: That error usually means that the sheet either doesn't exist where you're trying to copy it from or where you're copying it to.  Make sure you have a sheet called "Raw Data" (no quotes) in both workbooks.  Be sure to make sure it's not "Raw Data " or " Raw Data" (notice the spaces after and before the sheet name, which is an error that's more common than you'd think).  Also, I think that both workbooks have to be open...

Comment: also make sure _both_ your workbooks opened

Comment: In general, when you get an unhelpful error message from VBA like this, you have to look at the pieces in the debugger using Add Watch. Either look at the subexpressions directly, or create a temporary variable.

Answer (score 0):

This error tends to occur with Copy/Paste functions when the `Sub` is written at either worksheet or workbook level.

You should be able to solve your problem by creating a module, and pasting your code there.

Comment: @one14four did you encounter any issues with this?